# CasperJS and mint.com

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs

I have an account at mint.com and I'm trying to download information about my accounts daily. I haven't found a Mint API, I don't think Intuit and Yodlee APIs will work.

I want to get the data already in Mint, I'm trying to use CasperJS (on a Raspberry PI if that matters). Right now the following JavaSript will parse `https://www.google.com` just fine, but `https://www.mint.com` it just hangs.

```
var links = [];
var casper = require('casper').create();

function getLinks() {
    var links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
    return Array.prototype.map.call(links, function(e) {
        return e.getAttribute('href')
    });
}

casper.start('https://www.mint.com/', function() {

});

casper.then(function() {
    links = this.evaluate(getLinks);
});

casper.run(function() {
    // echo results in some pretty fashion
    this.echo(links.length + ' links found:');
    this.echo(' - ' + links.join('\n - ')).exit();
});
```

---

output for Mint

```
[info] [phantom] Starting...
[info] [phantom] Running suite: 3 steps
[debug] [phantom] opening url: https://wwws.mint.com/, HTTP GET
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://wwws.mint.com/, type=Other, lock=true, isMainFrame=true
[warning] [phantom] Loading resource failed with status=fail: https://wwws.mint.com/
[debug] [phantom] Successfully injected Casper client-side utilities
[info] [phantom] Step 2/3: done in 181787ms.
[info] [phantom] Step 3/3: done in 181893ms.
[info] [phantom] Done 3 steps in 181981ms
0 links found:
 -
```

---

output for google

```
[info] [phantom] Starting...
[info] [phantom] Running suite: 4 steps
[debug] [phantom] opening url: http://google.fr/, HTTP GET
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=http://google.fr/, type=Other, lock=true, isMainFrame=true
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=http://www.google.fr/, type=Other, lock=true, isMainFrame=true
[debug] [phantom] url changed to "http://www.google.fr/"
[debug] [phantom] Successfully injected Casper client-side utilities
[info] [phantom] Step 2/4 http://www.google.fr/ (HTTP 301)
[info] [remote] attempting to fetch form element from selector: 'form[action="/search"]'
[debug] [remote] Set "q" field value to casperjs
[info] [remote] submitting form to /search, HTTP GET
[info] [phantom] Step 2/4: done in 1901ms.
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=http://www.google.fr/search?hl=fr&source=hp&q=casperjs&gbv=2, type=FormSubmitted, lock=true, isMainFrame=true
[debug] [phantom] url changed to "http://www.google.fr/search?hl=fr&source=hp&q=casperjs&gbv=2"
[debug] [phantom] Successfully injected Casper client-side utilities
[info] [phantom] Step 3/4 http://www.google.fr/search?hl=fr&source=hp&q=casperjs&gbv=2 (HTTP 301)
[info] [remote] attempting to fetch form element from selector: 'form[action="/search"]'
[debug] [remote] Set "q" field value to phantomjs
[info] [remote] submitting form to /search, HTTP GET
[info] [phantom] Step 3/4: done in 4675ms.
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=http://www.google.fr/search?q=phantomjs&hl=fr&gbv=2&oq=&gs_l=, type=FormSubmitted, lock=true, isMainFrame=true
[debug] [phantom] url changed to "http://www.google.fr/search?q=phantomjs&hl=fr&gbv=2&oq=&gs_l="
[debug] [phantom] Successfully injected Casper client-side utilities
[info] [phantom] Step 4/4 http://www.google.fr/search?q=phantomjs&hl=fr&gbv=2&oq=&gs_l= (HTTP 301)
[info] [phantom] Step 4/4: done in 6478ms.
[info] [phantom] Done 4 steps in 6552ms
22 links found:
 - /url?q=http://casperjs.org/&sa=U&ei=SLQ6UbawMYOE9QSlooD4Bw&ved=0CBwQFjAA&usg=AFQjCNEivptk0tQ6060ZeJF2ZO7BDHisuQ
 - /url?q=http://casperjs.org/installation.html&sa=U&ei=SLQ6UbawMYOE9QSlooD4Bw&ved=0CB8QqwMoADAA&usg=AFQjCNEgDNPxz-NyxPI-XdGxcMM92VMu1g
 - /url?q=http://casperjs.org/quickstart.html&sa=U&ei=SLQ6UbawMYOE9QSlooD4Bw&ved=0CCAQqwMoATAA&usg=AFQjCNG1J2w6fPKdK_mASYGxFsnAWp21fw
```

CasperJs --version is 1.0.0-RC4

PhantomJs was compiled for RaspberryPI -> https://github.com/piksel/phantomjs-raspberrypi
version 1.7.0

A simple wget will download the html, so I must not have a setting or have setup CasperJs wrong? Other javascript enabled websites parse fine, but for Mint I get nothing?

Comment: Try using a different user agent – I wouldn't be surprised if a banking site blocks PhantomJS.

Comment: Your script works for me with latest master. Also, you may want to check that SSL is supported on your box.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a spelling mistake
the log shows...

```
opening url: https://wwws.mint.com/
```

is there a wwws in your URL?

Comment: That's quite a catch! :)